# How to create Authy (twilio) applications using API?

Tags: twilio, authy

I'm trying to figure out how to segment multiple customers in a SaaS app when using Twilio's Authy.

One of the ways is to create an application per customer (with/without sub-accounts per customer/customer-group). However, to onboard customers automatically I would like to create applications via API.

Authy's docs are unhelpful - https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/applications#create-new-application says "To create a new Authy application, click the red plus ('+') button from the console".

Is there a way to create an app from the API?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is not a way to create an Authy app from the API.

Comment: so what's the best practice? I get that Authy is Multi-Tenant, but what if your customer (me) is also a Multi-Tenant with automatic tenant registration and onboarding? Should we just lump everyone into the same account / authy application? that sounds less than desirable - both from security (user management) and user experience perspective (no custom logos, no split icons in the authy app) @philnash

Comment: I believe you are in contact with support who are now assessing your use case to see what the best course of action is for your application. That's going to be the best way to get a result here.